# I need a sample NCPDP/EDI file

Tags: format, message, standards, edi

I'm working with a program called MIRTH, but i've not been able to find a sample EDI/NCPDP file anywhere.
does anyone know where I can find one or have one on hand... I would be very happy if one were to respond to this message with a sample.

Thanks,

John.

Answer (score 2):

You can see some canned scripts here http://www.anshealth.com/validator.htm like the NewRx one below.

```
UNA:+.?*'UIB+UNOA:0++1234567+++epostRxDemo:C+epostRxDemo:P+20023927:093947:0000+ :2'UIH+SCRIPT:004:000:NEWRX+110072+++20023927:093947:0000+2'REQ'PVD+PC+6666666:OB++AM:FP+J:DOCTOR++++6152219800:TE'PVD+P2+7701630:D3++AM:FP+++MAIN STREET PHARMACY++6152205656:TE'PTT++19541225+Gadd:Steve:Steve+F+333445555:SY+1313 mockingbird lane:Warminster:PA:18966'DRU+P:CALAN SR 240MG::::240:ME+EA:60:38+1TID+85:20011001:102+0+R:1+2:junk+12345:OB++AD:  :  ::  +  'OBS'COO'UIT+110072+9'UIZ++1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same 'MIRTH', but here is an entire community around it

http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/index.php?s=b6990e9fe7bf68731f7075bd1412f336

I have never used MIRTH, but this looks promising ...